# React Native pantalla en blanco al hacer un checkout

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en React-Native. Total, que le he metido el Navigation, Stack y Tab para multiScreen. No me funcionaba y decidi borrar esos 3 y empezar de nuevo como lo llevaba previamente que al menos si mostraba mi App con su diseño, componentes etc. Total que para borrar esos 3 lo que hice fue un git checkout de App.js, Package.json y Yarn.lock. Ahora la pantalla se me ha quedado completamente blanca, no muestra absolutamente nada. Que puedo hacer? O que me he quedado por el camino. Gracias!

Comment: Muestra un [repro]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Al final lo solucione de manera simple: me canse de darle vueltas y reinstale Node_Modules